# Migration to Open Tooling for multi-application workspace

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to convert a multi-application project (v6.2) into a npm-based with webpack support.

Running `ext-gen migrate` fails with the error:
*Upgrade multi-application workspace is not yet supported*

1. Is it possible to stay on v6.2 and migrate to npm?
2. What is the correct way to do that?